# Fatest and elegent way to create a dict of dicts returning a list of data with repeated keys (two levels of key dict) from a 2d-list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Sorting data from huge lists with two levels of keys is helpful for interpreting dataset and calling by couple or one level of keys some slice of data, especially when creating plots.

I use a very naive and, I guess, inefficient way to create from a 2D-list of data a dict of dicts (two levels of keys) that returns a list of data.
How to make this code more elegant, possibly faster and more readable? I guess using collection module but I didn't find a smart way.

Example:

```
# create a dict of dict with two levels of keys that returns a list of data

listo = [['a',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],       # the 2D-list with the two first columns as the two levels of keys
         ['b',11,12,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         ['b',21,22,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         ['a',31,32,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         ['a',1,402,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         ['b',11,412,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         ['b',21,422,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         ['a',31,432,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]

# script to convert the 2D list to a dict (1st column) of dict (2nd column) 
dico = {}
for i in range(len(listo)) :
    a = listo[i][0]
    if a in dico:  #if 1st level of key already in the dict
        if listo[i][1] in dico[a]:  # if the 2nd level of key is already in the dict of the 1st level of key
            b=dico[a]
            c=b[listo[i][1]]
            c.append(listo[i][2:])
        else:
            b=dico[a]
            b[listo[i][1]]=[listo[i][2:]]
    else:
        dico[a]={listo[i][1]:[listo[i][2:]]}

# display the expected result (human-friendly)
for i in dico:
    print(i)
    for j in dico[i]:
        print(' ',j)
        for k in dico[i][j]:
            print('   ',k)
# display the expected result (as the dict of dict returning a list of data)        
print('\n\n',dico)
```

Expected dict of dicts returning list of data:

```
{'a': {1: [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [402, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], 31: [[32, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [432, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]}, 'b': {11: [[12, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [412, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], 21: [[22, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [422, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]}}
```

Thank for incoming advice and help.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal ? Do you plan to use pandas for example ?

Comment: no, no use of pandas. I would stay as far as possible using common core python.

Comment: It's a question of algorithm, rather than a 'help me with my problem' question. I have an answer (provided) that does the job. I feel my approach is very naive and I'm looking for a more elegant and faster algo/code in core python.

Comment: I am almost about to ask on meta why you have been downvoted twice. You ***demonstrate*** research efforts. Your question ***is*** reproducible. Hard to think of any duplicate given how peculiar your case is. Curious. We both miss something. I would be glad to know why if the downvoters come around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
ks0, ks1, *data = zip(*listo)

import collections as co
dicts = co.defaultdict(lambda: co.defaultdict(list))

for k0, k1, row in zip(ks0, ks1, zip(*data)):
    dicts[k0][k1].append(row)
```

---

Another ***100% preloaded built-in*** approach:

```
ks0, ks1, *data = zip(*listo)
dicts = {}

for k0, k1, row in zip(ks0, ks1, zip(*data)):
    dk0   = dicts[k0] = dicts.get(k0, {})
    dk0k1 = dk0[k1] = dk0.get(k1, [])
    dk0k1.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby
first=lambda l: l[0]

def group_by_first(listo):
    grouped = groupby(sorted(listo,key=first), key=first) #  group by first elem, need to sort first
    return {k: [e[1:] for e in g] for k,g in grouped} # remove key (first elem) from values

{k: group_by_first(l) for k,l in group_by_first(listo).items()} # group first elem and then by second
```

Comment: `first` could be `import operator as opr; first = opr.itemgetter(0)`

Comment: ty for your return, it's a compact proposal.